# Download file from virtual directory (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, download, virtual-directory, response

I need to download a file from a virtual directory when clicking on a button in sharepoint.

I've tried this:

```
page.Response.ContentType = "text/vcard";
page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + path);
page.Response.TransmitFile(page.Server.MapPath("~/vcf/" + path));
page.Response.Flush();
page.Response.End();
```

The problem with this is that I can download the file, but after downloading, I can't do anything on the page. I guess that's the Response.End(), but deleting that line doesn't work because he'll add text to my downloaded file...

Is there an easy solution to this? Or another (working) solution is always welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the web part (or whatever) that's rendering the button to include the following javascript into the page:

```
_spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;
_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;
```

Comment: OMG, you're my hero... been looking for this all day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Per, I'm new in both Asp.Net & Sharepoint. I already have a .js file registered for my WebPart, but I couldn't understand how I must include the code above: should I create a function with that, how I would run this code, etc. Can you help me with this?